# How can I change Environments variables in Electron between production and stage

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I want to change API URL depending on the environments.
for example

```
production: https://example.com
stage: https://stage.example.com
local: https://localhost:3001
```

In Electron, How can I set Environment variables?

I tried to change production name when I build but it was useless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, after packaging your app we can't pass the env variable.

I mean even if we try to define or add process env variable. It will be useless in production. I'd say `process.env.NODE_ENV` will be undefined on production mode. Recommend to use `electron-is-dev` to check if the app is in development mode or production mode.

**package.json**

```
"production": "electron-builder .",
"stage": "cross-env NODE_ENV=stage electron .",
"local": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron ."
```

at you **main.js** or **index.js**

```
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');

let apiURL = 'https://localhost:3001';

if (isDev) { // or if(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    // Dev or Stage
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'stage')
         apiURL = "https://example.com";
} else {
    // Prod mode
    apiURL = "https://example.com";
    console.log('Running in production');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There's no way to separate production with staging on production? production: (prod and stg) dev: (local)

Comment: Well, as far as I know, it's impossible.

Comment: ) My pleasure. Actually, there will be a more sophisticated way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

With node you can use `process.env`.

In your code:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
 // use production api
 const api = 'https://example.com';
}
```

or use a switch case:

```
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
 case 'production':
  // use production api
  const api = 'https://example.com';
  break;
 case 'stage':
  // use stage api
  const api = 'https://stage.example.com';
  break;
 case 'local':
  // use local api
  const api = 'https://localhost:3001';
  break;
 default:
  // use a default this api
}
```

And in your terminal when using Electron:

```
$ NODE_ENV=production electron index.js
```

Or add it as script in your Package.json

```
"production": "NODE_ENV=production electron index.js",
"stage": "NODE_ENV=stage electron index.js",
"local": "NODE_ENV=local electron index.js"
```

Then you can use it:

```
$ npm run production
$ npm run stage
$ npm run local
```

Comment: hmm...I want to change the variables after distribute. when I download electron app, I can't change it

Comment: Once your app is packed you need to change it manually in the source code. U can add a global api route and define this one in your app so you can just change the url in your api.

Comment: I don't  want to change manually. When I push to github. The CI will be triggered and electron-builder will run. After that, It will be automatically uploaded on AWS S3 and Each users application will be autoupdated. So when should I change it?